Automatically disconnect network drives when connection is interrupted
I use Virtual Machines on macOS via tart. To transfer files between the host and guest, I use SMB which is enabled in System Settings > General > Sharing > File Sharing. That works well.
The inconvenience arises when I quit the VM, which I do by just closing the window (state is saved). I always forget to disconnect SMB beforehand which means that after a few seconds I have this window pop up in my face:

My goal is to not have to deal with that. Ideally there's a setting somewhere that lets me tell macOS to just go ahead and disconnect interrupted server connections without prompting. In searching online, all I'm finding are people trying to do the opposite (auto-reconnect).
